# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. react native, currently trying to run on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am trying to run my react native application on Android and when I try

```
react-native run-android
```

I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

I have already tried cleaning Gradle.

```
>>cd android
>>./gradlew clean
```

After that I did `npm install` which gave me some warnings but no errors.

And then when i did `react-native run-android` it gave me an error. Could you please suggest what might be causing this to happen.

here is the full log.

```
   PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app> cd .\android\
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android> ./gradlew clean
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 12.533 secs
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android> react-native run-android
Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android> npm install
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@7.3.0 requires a peer of react@15.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@7.3.0 requires a peer of react-dom@15.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native@0.55.4 requires a peer of react@16.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.21.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-web-maps@0.1.0 requires a peer of react-native-web@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-prop-types-element-of-type@2.2.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.6 || ^15.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 12.877s
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android> react-native run-android
Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android> cd..
PS C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app> react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules (57ms)
(node:3392) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0554Library
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.038 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Answer (score 2):

i have the similar issue in Release build. I tried
"gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace" and it worked for me